# getPrincipal() method returns anonymous user

Tags: java, web-services, spring-security, roles

I'm trying to get the connected user via spring security method

```
public static User getConnectedUser() {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    User currentUser=auth.getPrincipal();
}
```

When i invoke this method from a webservice get method using postman it returns anonymousUser even if am logged in.
Here is my spring security configuration:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/passwordHint*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_ANONYMOUS')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/requestRecoveryToken*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_ANONYMOUS')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/updatePassword*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_ANONYMOUS')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/signup*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_ANONYMOUS')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" login-processing-url="/j_security_check"/>
    <remember-me user-service-ref="userDao" key="e37f4b31-0c45-11dd-bd0b-0800200c9a66"/>
    <custom-filter ref="ajaxTimeoutRedirectFilter" after="EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER"/>
</http>
```

Even when i added this line `<intercept-url pattern="/*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')"/>` to the above configuration it returns the anonymousUser.

Here is the url i request from postman.

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/services/api/seal/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yor `intercept-url` are all not match because your path begins with `services` not with `app`.

If your context root is `myApp`, your configuration should be:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/services/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
```

Comment: even with this `<intercept-url pattern="/*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')"/>` ?